# javascript module on function

Tags: javascript, function, module

I have a function that tries to find the lesser number of money using a JSON object. It works fine. But if I try to "explode" this value (67), the function instead of return me:

```
 { 
   '1':   0,
   '2':   1,
   '5':   1,
   '10':  1,
   '20':  0,
   '50':  1,
   '100': 0,
   '200': 0,
   '500': 0
}
```

return me:

```
 { 
   '1':   1,
   '2':   3,
   '5':   0,
   '10':  0,
   '20':  3,
   '50':  0,
   '100': 0,
   '200': 0,
   '500': 0
}
```

This is the code:

```
function money(value) {
   let size = { "500": 0, "200": 0, "100": 0, "50": 0, "20": 0, "10": 0, "5": 0, "2": 0, "1": 0 };
   if (value > 0) {
    while (value != 0) {
        if (value % 500 === 0) {
            size["500"]++;
            value -= 500;
        } else if (value % 200 === 0) {
            size["200"]++;
            value -= 200;
        } else if (value % 100 === 0) {
            size["100"]++;
            value -= 100;
        } else if (value % 50 === 0) {
            size["50"]++;
            value -= 50;
        } else if (value % 20 === 0) {
            size["20"]++;
            value -= 20;
        } else if (value % 10 === 0) {
            size["10"]++;
            value -= 10;
        } else if (value % 5 === 0) {
            size["5"]++;
            value -= 5;
        } else if (value % 2 === 0) {
            size["2"]++;
            value -= 2;
        } else if (value % 1 === 0) {
            size["1"]++;
            value -= 1;
        }
    }
 } else {
    console.log('\nSpiacente ma il numero inserito è negativo!');
 }

 return size;
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 value % 500 === 0
```

It just has to be:

```
 value >= 500
```

... same for all other comparisons.